# creation complete

Tags: apache-flex, itemrenderer

Can i use creation complete in item renderers , i have a data grid and i have kept every single cell as an item renderer. is it a good practice to use creation complete here. I fear events might fire up at wrong instances.suggestions are most welcomed.

Answer (score 2):

Use "dataChange" even instead.

More info at Adobe:
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=cellrenderer_7.html

> Flex might reuse an instance of the
>   item renderer or item editor, a reused
>   instance of an item renderer or item
>   editor does not redispatch the
>   creationComplete event. Instead, you
>   can use the dataChange event with an
>   item renderer or item editor. Flex
>   dispatches the dataChange event every
>   time the data property changes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with item renderers is that their number depends on the visible area and they are reused in flex.Scrolling issues are a very common problem in datagrids using itemrenderer such as Checkbox,TextInput etc., due to this.So dont use event handler on creationComplete .
There is always a work around :)

Comment: Then why the hell u did not tell about this when i started working on this module.....see now i am in a big fix..... :( arrgh ...

Comment: lol! see if i help you here many others can make use of it,isnt it? :)

Answer (score -1):

`creationComplete` is a phase in the flex application life cycle.

For more information you can go through the following link:

http://technobytz.com/flex-preinitialize.html